# Time depending C# application inside VM on Hyper-V

Tags: c#, server, timer, hyper-v, windows-server

I have created a class which im using for managing cronjobs inside of C#.

I can set an interval and it will use the System.Timers.Timer class inside to manage the timing.

I have now the following issue, when the root server gets rebooted (doesn't happen that often) all VMs get saved and later restored. But the timing will not change.

What does it mean, when I got a "offline" time of i.e. 5min, the Elapsed event of the Timer class comes 5 minutes later.

I tried to use the SystemEvents.TimeChanged and SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged events to get some feedback after a VM get restored and reset the timer.

Maybe somebody of you got a idea, how to fix this.

I have integration service likes time syncronisation enabled. The time get synced, but the TimeChanged event doesn't get fired.

Thank you !

Florian

Edit: Adding the project to my Git (https://github.com/MajMcCloud/CronjobBase)
Here is the file, which is important: https://github.com/MajMcCloud/CronjobBase/blob/main/Crontask.cs

Comment: off-topic comment: use Task Scheduler

Comment: its a good idea, but the issue i want to deliver tasks within a single application. For this i have to extract the business model. But thanks !

Comment: you need to save next run time somewhere and: after your app restart 1) set timer to Tick then (diff between now and next run) or 2) Tick with minimal required accuracy and check if it is right time 3) eventualy mark is task was runned and if not and time passed run it ... but seriosult Task Scheduler is the right choice (you can iterop Schedule.Service COM component to setup taks from c# code and execute your app with some parameter to do the job)

Comment: hm, the point is, the application will not get restarted, ether the system. It will just get saved and "restored" into memory. The main scheduler i developed worked fine. It is just about these special cases when the system time changed. Thanks

Comment: If your VM gets power-state events when it's suspended, then handling those events should work. If not, then you will have to poll to monitor the system clock and trigger the timer expiration based on that. See duplicates for discussion of both techniques. If you need help with some specific issue, post a new question that includes a [mcve], explain what the code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: I have attached my project for managing cronjobs. So you can take a look at the full code.

Comment: _"So you can take a look at the full code"_ -- **No.** That's not how Stack Overflow works. First of all, your question has already been answered. See duplicates. Secondly, if you need to post a new question, and thus need to provide a [mcve], you need to provide that [mcve] **as part of the question itself**. No one wants to read the entire project's worth of code, and code for SO questions and answers is **required** to be included as part of those posts themselves, not as links to external resources. Please read [ask] and the rest of the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Hm, i thought i have explained already what the issue is about. Your posts doesn't helped. I have read them through already. I can provide you an example, but it will not help, cause you did not understand the situation itself. And you do not have to read it, I just upload it cause you asked for. Thats the reason why i stayed away of these forums for almost 20 years...

Keep it, first and last time on stackoverflow.